# How to replace backslash \ in R with gsub?

Tags: r, gsub

I would like to ammend some .tex files from within R.
I read the file with readLines() but I cannot replace the following text.

```
tex <- "$\\times$"
new_tex <- gsub("$\\times$", "\\ $\\times$", tex)
new_tex
```

It seems that it cannot find the `$\\times$`
But even if it does, is it possible to write \ without escaping them?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: gsub uses regular expressions by default unless you set fixed=TRUE, and $ means the end of the sentence in reg.exp. So, use `new_tex <- gsub("$\\times$", "\\ $\\times$", tex,fixed=TRUE)`. And no, you can't write a backslash without escaping it, otherwise for example it would be impossible to distinguish between \t (backslash + t) and tab character ?

Comment: thank you, if you post it as an answer I will set it as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gsub` uses regular expressions by default unless you set `fixed=TRUE`.
In regular expressions `$` means the end of the sentence , that's why it does not work.

This, instead should work :

`new_tex <- gsub("$\\times$", "\\ $\\times$", tex,fixed=TRUE)`

About the backslash, no, you can't write a backslash without escaping it. Otherwise, for example, it would be impossible for the R interpreter, to distinguish between a tab `\t` and a "backslash + t".

Answer (score 0):

Without `fixed = TRUE`:

```
gsub("\\$\\\\times\\$", "\\\\ $\\\\times\\$", tex)
[1] "\\ $\\times$"
```

Unfortunately you need a lot of backslashes because you need to escape pretty much everything.